# Install java on linux server programmatically

Tags: java, linux, git, maven, jenkins

I am trying to set up the environment with Java, git, Jenkins and maven by mentioning the IP address of linux VM. I have written a code to connect to VM, create folders, and move files to folders.

Now I want to install all Java and others software programmatically. Ib tried to install Java using `yum -y install java-1.7.0`. There is no error but then Java is not installed.

Please suggest what needs to be done so that Java gets installed and java_home path is set programmatically.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are you running your commands from jenkins jobs or how you are running your commands? please elaborate.

Comment: Hi @AbhijeetKamble, I am connecting to Linux VM using JscH. I am able to connect to VM and execute commands like mkdir,rm etc..all these commands are executed using Java secure channel in exec mode...

Comment: Check out a tool like [Ansible](http://www.ansible.com/home) - it has everything you need, and there are existing roles for installing Java (https://galaxy.ansible.com/list#/roles/1209).

Comment: I did this with a bunch of bash scripts, but I used apt-get on Ubuntu and don't know yum.

Comment: @nwinkler, Thank you for suggesting it. This is a paid tool and i am looking at open source tool or code which can do this for us.. please let me know if you are familiar about any such tool or piece of code

Comment: Ansible is actually open source - you can install and use it for free: https://github.com/ansible/ansible

Comment: You should be able to install the latest version of Ansible using yum: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_installation.html#latest-release-via-yum

Comment: @nwinkler , I read through the documentation and its saying that Ansible needs to be installed on Linux machines. But my intention is to set the configuration from windows onto the linux machine.

Comment: @Gustave, can you please share it.. or direct me towards any such document which can this on Linux 7(RHEL)

Comment: Any one has any suggestion?

Comment: I am able to copy the jdk zip file into linux server and able to extract the files. But one problem i am currently facing is that "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" is not updating the path variable when executed through Java. But "export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin" is working when executed through putty. Any idea on how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

We've been doing this at the office this week. It sounds like you want a solution which would include JscH because you've started down that path.  What I have to offer you is a solution that uses Jenkins.

We set up a target machine (two actually) as Jenkins slaves. It's rather easy to do, but you do need to install a JVM.  You might look at docker.

Once the Jenkins slave is connected to the jenkins master, we just instruct it to run scripts. Some commands require sudo and so we set that up so that it does not require a password to be entered.  Alternatively, you could run the jenkins slave jar after already having sudo -- not recommended.

We made a pom.xml to fetch .jar files and tar.gz files out of maven and copy them into a specific location. Then we executed scripts that manipulated them. The scripts came out of version control via Jenkins, but other files we pulled out of version control using a script.

All in all, I have the following tips for you:

1. Debug a script by executing it without Jenkins, and then run it under Jenkins for some final debug.
2. Put plenty of echo statements into your scripts so that you can see what has gone wrong.
3. You're totally relying on the Jenkins log and print debugging. This is very time consuming.  So you would do well to pay attention to point #1.

Good luck :-)

Comment: I have never worked with Jenkins. Can you please share step-by-step info on what needs to be done. Or else any useful link or document which helps in achieving this.

Comment: I was able to achieve this by executing linux commands through java